# Build Configurations with Facebook SDK for iOS in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, app-id, buildconfiguration

I have configured an app with server and client components for Facebook. But since one app can only have 2 URLs (including the mobile site URL), I had to create another app for the development environment and register localhost there. You can tell Facebook that the second app is the test version of the first app, but you still get two different AppIDs. Since the Facebook SDK expects the AppID key to be in `Info.plist::FacebookAppID` (Swift) I wonder how to put in the keys for both apps and let the compiler choose the right one depending on your build configuration?

This must be a something very common, so I'm surprised I couldn't find any answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the AppID for the Production App also works with the Test App (but not the other way round), so I won't need an extra key for different build configurations.

**Edit:**
After removing and redeploying the app from the iPhone simulator, the key for the production app didn't work on the test app anymore. It was probably some kind of a cache thing. So, problem still not solved.